# Should the Roomba's standards be different for Meta?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, meta, automatic-deletion

I totally disagree with the premise of this question, but I don't think it should be deleted. In fact, I don't even think it should be closed!

- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278524/voting-doesnt-provide-a-clear-and-useful-feedback-mechanism (10k link)

I wanted to vote to close this question as a duplicate https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297060/specifying-the-useful-and-non-useful-post-by-users-is-wrong-and-baseless (because there's a ton of questions like that one), and referring them to such a signpost would be helpful for the asker of that question. But it's already gone!

So, I guess I'm saying a few things:

1. I think we should be more careful about voting to close questions **on meta** that we don't like. Just because we don't agree with the question doesn't mean it should be closed, it just means **it should be downvoted**.
2. I think the roomba should be more careful about what it deletes on Meta. Because downvoting means "disagree", and not "poor quality" - the 10k link there is a very well written articulation of an idea I disagree with - we should try to keep these questions around more often.
3. The 10k link above was closed as a duplicate of a question that it's not a duplicate of. "Voting isn't clear or useful" is **very different** from "downvoters must leave a comment".

Comment: What is "Roomba"?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Closing had very little to do with that question's deletion. As a reminder, [here are the rules for automatic deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year):

> **If the question is more than `30` days old, and ...**
>
> - has −1 or lower score
> - has no answers
> - is not locked
>
> **...or...**
>
> - it was closed and migrated to a different site
>
> ... it will be automatically deleted. Internally, these are termed
>   "dead" questions.
>
> **If the question is more than `365` days old, and ...**
>
> - has a score of 0, **or** a score of 1 in case of deleted owner
> - has no answers
> - is not locked
> - has view count <= the age of the question in days times 1.5
> - has 1 or 0 comments
>
> ... it will be automatically deleted. These are "abandoned" questions.
>
> **If the question was closed more than `9` days ago, and ...**
>
> - not closed as a duplicate
> - has a score of 0 or less
> - is not locked
> - has no answers with a score > 0
> - has no accepted answer
> - has no pending reopen votes
> - has not been edited in the past `9` days
>
> ... it will be automatically deleted. These are "abandoned closed".

The question you linked to scored < 0, was not answered, not locked, and more than 30 days old.

Therefore...

1. The question was closed **because it was a duplicate.** You can debate this if you like, and had 30 days during which that might've been productive; if you wish to debate it now, you should also vote to undelete the question.
2. The question was massively unpopular. I don't just mean it was downvoted, although it was; it didn't get a single answer during the time it was open, or a single reopen vote after it was closed *even when it was added to [reopen review](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/2416).* This wasn't one of those useful discussions where the originator is wrong but the answers helpfully explain why; it was yet another in a long, long series of laments about other people not doing something that would benefit the author.
3. Again, the time to debate this was back in December. If no one full of Holiday Cheer cared to try alchemy on that post then, I don't see it happening now; it would just add to the clutter. If you're particularly interested in seeing further discussion on it, then why not post it yourself?

Comment: `If you're particularly interested in seeing further discussion on it, then why not post it yourself?` Or just hold that discussion in any of the other rants about downvotes that's asked several times a day, every day, without adding *yet another one*.

Answer (score 3):

> referring them to such a signpost

The question has 85 views over 6 months.  It was very clearly *not* acting as a signpost.

If that post would have been getting a lot of views, and was actively serving as a signpost, then *the roomba wouldn't have deleted it*.