# What areas of Stack Overflow need answering help?

Tags: discussion, tags, unanswered-questions

I have been using Stack Overflow for at least two years, and I feel like there is not a lot of work left to do in the R and Python tags (what I know best.)

Are there any tags that need more love? Or that have many unanswered questions?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that learning a new technology brings far more rewards than being able to answer SO questions of that technology. :)

Comment: No, every programming question already have an answer, thanks to the community.

Comment: See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318719/why-are-answer-rates-dropping

Comment: What is the community's position on this issue? Does it believe we have created a saturated knowledge base that just needs occasional cleanup?

Comment: See [Help us clean up the Android tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252860/1288) for a (long-running) query that will give you unanswered count on popular tags, along with some pointers on helping to clean up "problem" tags. You can also go directly to the [Top Users](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/android/topusers) tag info tab for the unanswered % for the past week, month, and all time for an individual tag.

Comment: Instead of a specific tag, try answering [popular "unanswered questions"](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers)?

Answer (score 0):

No.

Some tags are more popular than others, that's just how it is. Answering more questions in unpopular tags to bridge the gap is not going to change that.

People will learn software as and when the need arises and the questions will follow accordingly. People who're well versed in the software already will continue to do their thing and answer. If it isn't broken, don't fix it.

Comment: Disappointed by this answer... It should include a SEDE query with the ratio of unanswered questions per tag :(

Comment: @user000001 I ran some mental queries and wrote this. Sorry, the tech is proprietary so I can't share results with you ;)