# Is Stack Overflow becoming an error-detection site?

Tags: discussion, question-quality, typographical-error, debugging-questions

Recently I have noticed that more and more questions that really are syntax mistakes, and really small mistakes that could easily be fixed.

Why is this bad? If you see many older posts prior to ~2012, you will notice that many posts can be questions for many users not one in particular. For example, "What does this function do?", "How can it be used?", etc.

However when we look at more modern ones, a majority if not all questions are to the tune of, "What's wrong with MY program?". Questions like these have little to no insight for users other than the OP.

My real question (as a user somewhat new to Stack Overflow) is: has this always been the case? Because if not, this can be seriously detrimental to Stack Overflow.

Comment: As long as I can remember, there have always been trivial or highly localized debugging questions on this site, but the site was built to help weed them out, or at least have them sink to the bottom and allow higher quality questions to percolate to the top.

Comment: Also be careful to note that the passage of time can make it seem that the older posts are better, when it may simply be that the junk from back then has long since been removed, but the junk from now is still in the process of being removed.

Comment: @StephenRauch Except that the site is going out of its way to take steps to stop people from removing, or providing feedback on, the low quality content, and are taking steps to actively encourage it.

Comment: Those kinds of questions have been asked all the time I've been here. But the proportion *feels* higher.

Comment: There is a current trend of calling just about anything "too broad" on the main site, and saying that just about anything with code "requires an mvce". Certain posts need to be narrowed; certain posts need to have a stronger example to demonstrate the issue. That said, too many of the posts that are closed with this reason are in fact well demonstrated or narrow enough to answer. The result of such a zealous interpretation of lacking mvce or too broad is that the only resulting questions allowed is the narrow one with an exact mvce, demonstrating some nuance that rarely helps future users.

Comment: Our users gleefully closing questions thinking they are helping everyone out are in fact taking a misguided version of the close reasons and turning us into a site that is only useful for refactoring snippets. We seriously need to revisit the structure of our close reasons, so that these same users can gleefully help the site instead of contributing to a problem they didn't create but have become wrapped up in.

Comment: Maybe it's just nostalgia, but I feel like the quality went sharply downhill around 2013-2014, although I don't think it got much worse since then. Before 2012 was still early days (remember the site only launched late 2008), before all the help vampires knew about the blood bank.

Comment: @Dukeling - You mean, exactly when "Too Broad" and "Off topic: mcve" were introduced; or, more precisely, when the close reasons were changed?

Comment: Well, when faced with a question from an OP who, essentially, is imcompetent to program computers, all we have are left is a coin-toss between 'Unclear' and 'Too broad'.  That, or wait for some 100k+ rep cucumber to copy/paste in an answer for another 50 rep.

Comment: @MartinJames - Certain questions *need* to be closed, I am not disagreeing that your example, perhaps slightly harsh in its analysis, happens often. However, all too often those reasons are used to close questions we should have left open. Clarifying the use of these reasons, and making them not only more granular but less vague, will allow us to not only still close your example question, but also avoid falling into the trap of closing questions which would otherwise actively generate quality content and retain users.

Comment: There is a perfect solution for these kind of questions. Answer them in comments and flag as off-topic: "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a **simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting. "

Comment: If the answer can't be closed as a dupe (because it isn't) and the issue is more than an actual typo the best solution imo is to write an answer that goes beyond the op and adresses the general aspect of this kind of error. This may well include editing the question, esp. the title to make the actual issue clearer and make the question easier to find, both when looking for an answer and when looking for a dupe..

Comment: One's own perception of SO 'getting worse' in terms of question quality is also impacted by our experience; as one spends more time on SO and becomes a more competent programmer, one inevitably becomes more cynical and fed-up with low quality content

Comment: @Servy I thought that SO is trying to make us more understanding and helpful to new users so that we don't scare them away. Are you saying that this means that we shouldn't clean up their content when needed as well?

Comment: Personally, I think that the problem resides in laziness and hungry for reputation: 1) those questioners feel that StackOverflow is a place in which they could get their problems solved with no effort and 2) users who respond to them (I do that occasionally, I have to admit) knows that they going to have easy rep in return (because the system allows that). The second point, then, feeds the first one, creating an endless cycle between the two facts.

Comment: @Andreaジーティーオー such are the costs of gamifying a help source.

Comment: @Chris_Rands One also keeps seeing variants of the same few questions over and over and over and over again. Although I guess some people use that as an opportunity to master writing the same answer over and over again. This also makes one (or me, at least) think a lot about the future value of questions, and then you start seeing the lack of future value in too many other questions as well.

Comment: @Alex No, I'm not saying we shouldn't clean up their content.  I'm saying it's very important that we do.  I'm saying that SO is making changes to make that happen much less often though, and that's going to cause problems in the long term.

Comment: @TravisJ It was probably the removal of "too localized" (and "not a real question" and "not constructive"?) that affected quality more than the addition of close reasons. I'd actually be really curious whether anyone investigated whether and how close votes changed after that - did people shift their close votes to the new reasons or did they just stop close voting (on some or all questions)? And were they voting well before? Looking back, all of [that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154) looks like the "be more welcoming" for closing, and more bad questions were indeed welcomed.

Comment: @Servy As someone who acts to moderate the content of the site as a non-diamond user on a near-daily basis, I have seen no evidence of this. Most changes to content moderation have improved either the quality of user feedback or the toolset provided to users doing the moderating.

Comment: @TylerH SO has been working as hard as they can to prevent people from ever commenting on posts, trying to encourage people to just not comment at all, and to try to get as many comments as possible deleted when they're posted anyway, lowering the standards for deletion to, "delete everything", to a close approximation.  They've also tried to get people to "be welcoming" to new users, which a huge portion of the user base interprets as "don't cast close votes or downvotes", and given how misleading the messages from SO are, I can only assume that's the intended implication.

Comment: @Servy That is an incredibly jaded and untruthful view. SO has not been working to prevent people from commenting at all. They have cleaned up comment flagging to make it easier to flag unwelcoming content. But unwelcoming content is not helping people, it has the opposite effect. SO also hasn't tried to get people to stop close-voting or downvoting... despite the fact that certain loud individuals on Meta jump to that conclusion every time the staff makes a post. Contrarily, the staff has introduced new features recently to get more people to cast CVs and DVs via the red review queue icon.

Comment: As SO continues to grow and build a collection of helpful, "general" answers, I'd imagine that questions will continue to become more specific. Users are more likely to have already found a solution to their problem using the ever-growing base of general knowledge, and if not, they likely have touched on one but are having trouble implementing it in their specific use-case. This isn't the sole reason of course, but as a library grows and adds books, eventually it's inevitable that they'll need to start covering more specific topics if they want to keep adding books :)

Comment: @TylerH There appears to be *a lot* of people who don't seem to understand what's wrong with certain comments deemed "unwelcoming", leaving them mostly unable to leave a comment they can be at least fairly sure is "welcoming" enough, so that certainly discourages commenting. SO says "be more welcoming", and it's simply a fact that downvoting, closing and deleting is not welcoming. Now of course you can argue that's not what they meant, but that doesn't stop people from jumping to that conclusion anyway.

Comment: @Dukeling My point is that it's unreasonable to say that the assumptions of some users are what SO's intentions are. I agree with you that there are a disturbingly large group of users on SO who seem unaware of basic etiquette and social expectations, but luckily the comment overhaul also included guidance for moderators to reach out to users and let them know why their comment was removed, and moderators have long had the ability to leave a custom message or send a direct message to users regarding unwelcoming behavior, if necessary.

Comment: @TylerH The problem is that SO has defined "unwelcoming" as basically any comment ever.  It's pretty much impossible to write a comment that *someone* won't find offensive or [mis]interpret as sarcastic or condescending, and a mod will always delete it.  They've demonstrated, through their examples of what they consider appropriate and inappropriate, that comments simply aren't welcome.  If they were *actually* trying to get rid of comments that were insulting, offensive, rude, or otherwise *actually* inappropriate, I wouldn't have a problem with it.  The red review icon is several years old.

Comment: @TylerH There's been plenty of discussion here about what constitutes "unwelcoming", but, even after all of that, people still don't seem to get what SO wants from them. The more you try to explain something to someone who can't understand it, the more you'll frustrate them and they'll just end up never commenting again, leaving or getting banned.

Comment: See this ques: [Question quality is dropping on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252506/1417185)

Comment: It's September. SO is much higher-quality during the summer when all the students aren't getting help with their homework.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

## Yes and the process began almost the moment the site launched

Some of [my earliest questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1438/jon-ericson?tab=questions&sort=newest&page=2) tell the tale:

- August 18, 2008—[Why shouldn't I “bet the future of the company” on shell scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17231/why-shouldnt-i-bet-the-future-of-the-company-on-shell-scripts)
- August 19, 2008—[Should a wireless network be open? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32964/should-a-wireless-network-be-open)
- August 27, 2008—[Why does StackOverflow use UserVoice for bugs and feature requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30853/why-does-stackoverflow-use-uservoice-for-bugs-and-feature-requests) (deleted)

I found these questions fun to ask, but as time went on, I got more and more pushback from other users who didn't enjoy them as much as I did. I eventually [quit the site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42481/the-problem-with-extrinsic-motivation) because it wasn't fun for me anymore. Every now and then one of my old questions (rightly) gets closed or deleted and I ponder what might have been.

What we figured out in the beta was the primary difference between a good question and a bad one is whether it can be answered. And by answered, I mean answered in a way that can be objectively evaluated (and voted upon). As we encountered novel questions, we started to see patterns of questions that work well and questions that don't. And so we developed some rules of thumb to help us [close questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions). Over time, we've [adjusted those rules](https://stackoverflow.blog/2013/06/25/the-war-of-the-closes/) based on how they have been applied on the site.

It turns out **asking answerable questions is hard**. [I've argued](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252149/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-stack-overflow/304135#304135) that most users would be better off answering before asking. It also turns out that asking about your own code is the easiest sort of question to successfully ask. So most of [our guidance on asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) focuses on debugging questions. It sure doesn't hurt that the people most likely to ask questions (new users) are usually motivated to ask by problems in their code. In our efforts to help people ask answerable questions, such as the [question template experiment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357951/what-can-we-put-in-a-question-template-to-help-people-ask-better-questions), we've focused in on questions about errors in the asker's code.

## One secret technique to make things better

> Ask your own questions! Maybe consider [self-answering too](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/05/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/)!

## Why it's not all bad

When I have a question about my code, I search Google and look for Stack Overflow results. More often than not, I find the answer to my question as an answer to a question from someone who had *exactly my problem*. Yes, the code is different, but the differences are mostly unimportant to the root problem, such as identifier names. As long as the title and tags are well-crafted, I can usually find my solution. Even if they are not, text in the question or answers can be enough for Google to point me in the right direction. It turns out these seemly selfish questions often help other people who have the same problem. In fact, this is one of the reasons Stack Overflow works so well.

One of the misgivings we heard about the ill-fated Documentation project was [how does it improve upon existing Q&A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343678/whats-documentation-for)? As the meta question says:

> Stack Overflow Q&A helps people get information they need in two simple ways that we clearly understand, and has done since its inception:
>
> - People can ask questions about real problems they have and receive answers, immediately helping the asker
> - So long as questions are generic enough and their titles are clear enough, people with problems can easily Google them and find the answer to their exact problem
>
> You can of course argue about which of these mechanisms is more important and fundamental to how Stack Overflow operates <sub><sup>(correct answer: it's the second! it's the second!)</sup></sub>, but I think we're all pretty clear that they're both there and that they both broadly work.

Also, debugging questions that provide enough code *really are easier to answer*. When I was [working to earn 1k with a sock puppet](https://jericson.github.io/tag/race_to_1k.html), I got so excited to see new Ruby questions about some error in the asker's code. Not only did it help me earn reputation, but I also learned a lot about Ruby when constructing [my answers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7948068/kathryn?tab=answers&sort=votes). Maybe I'm an oddball in enjoying debugging, but I sure do like a good puzzle. (It's gratifying to make a difference in someone else's life too, I suppose.)

## Realistically, all the good non-debugging questions have been asked

Ok, maybe not *all*, but many. We can infer that just by looking at the rate new questions are marked as a duplicate:

[image: Answers per question and duplicates over the years]

The answers per question decline also indicates these are questions that have one, definitive answer. If another answer has already pointed out the bug, why write up another answer? But many non-debugging questions can be answered several ways and tend to attract more answers.

If you want to see new questions that aren't about debugging, your best bet is to frequent the tag of a new language or technology. The world probably doesn't need another question about [Java arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+arrays), but there are probably a lot of unasked fundamental questions about, say, [Rust or Kotlin](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2018#most-loved-dreaded-and-wanted). Or, if you are only interested in established technologies, it doesn't hurt to go back to old questions that might have outdated answers and provide your own perspective.

Comment: +1 for this nugget: `it doesn't hurt to go back to old questions that might have outdated answers and provide your own perspective`. This is now standard practice for me. Users should be motivated too: a good answer on an old post is more likely to attract views and upvotes. On `Ask your own questions! Maybe consider self-answering too!` sadly the old-timers here repeatedly say `self-answered Q&A is held to a higher standard`, which is a rubbish idea, there should only be one objective standard. Sadly, I see good self-answered Q&A downvoted + discouraged.

Comment: @jpp: My tip for self-answered questions: write the question, write the answer, rewrite the question as if the answer didn't exist (this is the hard part) and post. When you get downvotes, just remember [haters gonna hate](https://giphy.com/gifs/haters-gonna-hate-nqp20clN05Mu4).

Comment: Why rewrite the question as if the answer doesn't exist?

Comment: @CharlieBrumbaugh: Sometimes the asker doesn't include enough information for someone else to answer. This is often true of other questions too, but at least in that case the asker can be forgiven since they don't know what answerers need. That's not true with a self-answer.

Comment: Please show 0-indexed graphs, not 1-indexed graphs, otherwise you're introducing a visual bias.

Comment: Visually insert a half-inch below the last line on the chart, @Cœur. Both scales are 1-indexed, and AFAIK neither measurement has ever been less than 1. Arguably the most misleading part of the chart is that the two scales have no connection - but that's ok for the purpose, as Jon isn't trying to find a balance between them, he's just illustrating that the two are trending in different directions.

Comment: It seems like the right axis should be the domain of the percentage, unless... is the percentage of duplicates really *also* only in the range of 1%-5%?

Comment: @TravisJ: I can't see any other way to read that axis unless it's just flat mislabeled.

Comment: @TravisJ: Yes, that is the duplicate rate. With the public data, [the query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/897946#graph) times out unless we look at a sample, but the results are similar. You can also [query the close rate](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/882802#graph) and that's at ~11% this year. [Roughly 40% of closed questions are closed as duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/question-close-stats), so that's a 4.5% duplicate rate this year. Probably more duplicates are undetected and unclosed.

Comment: The questions that bother me are the ones I'm convinced no-one (who's looking for it) will be able to find through Google. They may be easy to answer, but... they're easy to answer - it's often some trivial issue (for me), i.e. it's not interesting to answer or even just read. The ones that do have some underlying complexity are often ruined by unnecessary code and lack of focus on the specific issue, meaning they don't have much future value as it stands, and I can't really just rewrite the question (and code), especially when answers focus on parts I'd want to edit out. So... it's mostly bad

Comment: *Realistically, all the good non-debugging questions have been asked* Exactly! How many times do you have to answer [How to compare Strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) or [What is a Null Pointer Exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) or explain why [trying to parse XML/HTML/XHTML or any other non-regular language with regular expressions is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: @feelingunwelcome: [Once](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates) at most.

Comment: well if I am going to have to ask and answer my own questions, I will just put up a site like [Baeldung.com](https://www.baeldung.com/) and get not just the credit for doing the work but also whatever financial rewards I can eek out on the side for the less effort that I have ever put into SO. Which might be small but small is always more than ZERO which is what SO provides right now.

Comment: @feelingunwelcome: If you don't find value in asking questions on Stack Overflow and do find value in participating elsewhere, I encourage you do what you find rewarding. I'm serious: answering questions should be enjoyable and [even outright fun](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 54):

> Is Stack Overflow becoming an error detection site?

I think it's fair to say it's becoming *more* an error detection site than it once was. There are three factors contributing to this in my opinion.

#### Why and How

Consider most problems can be divided into "Why" and "How" components, i.e. "Why is XYZ true?" and "How can I apply XYZ?" XYZ can be an observed behaviour, how a feature works, what some function/syntax is used for, etc.

Many of the "Why" questions in popular tags have been asked long ago. Sure, technologies change, new technologies emerge, and new features developed. Hence the "Why" questions will never disappear.

However, as those "Why" questions cover more ground, you will find only questions struggling to *apply* the invaluable knowledge embedded in those old Q&A. These are the debugging questions.

#### Shift in SO purpose

There was a time, perhaps ~4 years ago, when SO Inc was interested in the suggestions of SO's core user base. These suggestions concern moderation, which is the cornerstone of how SO has been successful over the years. The focus has fundamentally changed. It's more important to keep the new user base, however fragmentary or passing their nature, happier than the experts who volunteer their time answering and moderating. Less moderation by experts means less ability to filter for pearls.

The shift has been [indicated in a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1438/jon-ericson). In my opinion, it needs expansion and, ultimately, correction:

> There is no doubt we've stopped making changes for core users and your
>   observations about how that's gotten worse ring true to me. And we've
>   certainly seen negative feedback on meta (downvotes being the most
>   trivial). The result may not be what you hope for, however. Often (and
>   more often recently) I've heard colleagues dismiss meta feedback.
>   Nobody wants to listen to relentless negativity.

#### Shift in the user base

This is a more contentious argument and part justification of why SO *may* have changed tack. It's moved with the times. Over the past decade more and more users of programming languages are not enthusiast or professional programmers. An enthusiast or professional programmer will be *interested* in knowing why something works and endeavor to understand how to apply that knowledge. Yes, they might even enjoy the task.

But increasingly we are seeing user who are programmers **out of necessity**. Ad-hoc tasks in the workplace required by people in non-IT roles and school projects involving programming are increasingly common. This will continue as more of the world becomes more IT literate.

What I fear is we'll end up with something like [The Little Black Bag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Little_Black_Bag). For those not familiar with this classic sci-fi story, it's a set of tools which performs miracles but nobody understands. Because users increasingly focus on the end product of *applying* more than theoretical *understanding*. The latter is more powerful, the former requires less effort but is, ultimately, dangerous.

Comment: I don't think "Why" questions have ever been a problem or declined. The problem is most answerers (at least inexperienced ones) seemingly unable to comprehend that someone wants to understand a concept more so than (or even instead of) how to solve some perceived problem arising from said concept. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/246665 And many of those who *can* comprehend it vote to close such questions as off-topic or primarily opinion-based, despite the questions clearly expecting factual answers. These people are actively trying to make Stack Overflow a debugging site.

Comment: @BoltClock, I see what you're saying. But isn't this caused indirectly by "Shift in SO Purpose"? By servicing new users only, you are expanding your user base, while alienating experts. There was some nice chart of this somewhere. In the tags I follow, a good question *usually* gets a good answer on the "why" front. It's not a problem in tags still visited by experts willing to answer.

Comment: I don't disagree with your main points, but you've only been an SO member for 8 months so you must be a true SO scholar to have derived this longer perspective narrative ;)

Comment: @jpp For sure, don't take it as a criticism, your work-rate on SO is obviously very high!

Comment: There's a nugget of truth in "Shift in SO purpose" but I'm afraid my comment has been more misunderstood than understood. (And that's my own fault for being unclear, by the way.) One of the things we learned in the Documentation project is that what people say on meta and what happens on the site are not always aligned. So we're now making an effort [consider more data points](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314799/why-we-initiated-the-latest-round-of-design-changes-and-the-role-of-meta). Also, our PMs, devs and designers have been more active on meta in the last year or so.

Comment: @JonEricson I think it's more than just a nugget of truth. When SO started, it had decades of technologies to fill the site with good questions that encourage positive feedback between established users and new users. This kept it going for all these years. But the site has reached the point of saturation where the amount of "good" content for existing tech has been exhausted. So now the rate of "good" content slows down to the real-time rate of new technologies. Now everything is either debugging or duplicate - neither of which are good for retaining new users.

Comment: @Mysticial: I think debugging questions are good at retaining the sort of people who enjoy answering them. If you don't enjoy answering them, there's no reason you can't ask and answer the sort of question you do enjoy. Obviously, that's more work than just answering, but maybe it will set an example for others to follow?

Comment: @JonEricson I have some opinions on this topic which I've [mentioned in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/43790088#43790088) - some of which are borderline taboo in terms of breaking with SO tradition. (Pardon my profanity and name-calling in the transcript - that's just what we do in the Lounge.)

Comment: I think debugging questions would be super useful *if we encouraged folks to teach debugging*, @Jon. For some reason there's a massive reluctance to do that however, from almost everyone. So what we get instead is... Patches. Folks post broken code, someone else patches it. Not universally - some folks *do* teach debugging, and some folks do it well - but also not well; there's a tremendous amount of "cargo-cult debugging" in some tags, with folks tossing out untested solutions to poorly-understood problems and hope for the best. The coding equivalent of using The Foxfire Book to treat cancer.

Comment: @Shog9 Oh, I really love teaching the questioners how to debug or how to solve their problems in general. But more than often, the questioners are reluctant to *learn* something, but “just want their problem fixed” and will even tell you that. And we do, what we were told to do in this case, move along and let them alone, as everything else could be interpreted as “not being welcoming”. So don’t be surprised that only those “cargo-cult debugging” people remain, not being able to teach something, they have no conflict with just posting “the solution” or actually some arbitrary untested code.

Comment: I want to learn but my boss wants me to finish my job. I have limited time to learn and complete the job. The job that i am not completely aware because of my lack of experience and working time. So nothing goes as planned and everytime gets broken while development. I have progress some then rollback some. Not just my lack of knowledge but also tools and computers and other stuff are not very consistent to hang on over one project, they can broke and stop or rollback the project too. Boss wants his product, We keep learning but always on a tight schedule, train never stops.

Comment: https://gutenberg.ca/ebooks/kornbluth-littleblack/kornbluth-littleblack-00-h.html

Answer (score 11):

I think it depends upon your perspective, which is almost completely constructed by the tags that interest you. I started in [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c), which is *notorious* for doubling as an indicator that a new CS semester started somewhere by an influx of pointer-arithmetic questions.

However, a lot of interesting stuff was going on in [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) because the author of one of the most popular books was answering questions, and folks that initially followed Jeff and Joel tended to gravitate toward Microsoft technologies.

Yet, when [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) took root and someone asked "what does headers already sent by ..." for the millionth time, Jeff compared it to, well, some not-so-nice things on Twitter.

[c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) was so fed up with off-by-one bugs and people that honestly didn't understand even the basics of the language, that they fought vehemently to allow recommended book lists on the site so they had *somewhere* to point people that vastly underestimated the amount of work the task ahead of them was going to need in order to be accomplished competently.

This was all in the first couple of years. Heck, some of it in the first few *months*.

The system worked, and works. Canonical questions surfaced, duplicates were a challenge but not *impossible* to handle efficiently, and the biggest problem that weighed on people's minds was more the decline in the quality of *writing* than the usefulness of any given question.

Fast forward and our volume has increased by over tenfold. As Jon indicates, almost *any* question that *isn't* about a specific problem in someone's code is probably a duplicate, unless it's dealing with a new technology. Wikipedia is facing this in more pronounced ways.

Even questions about when one might argue with the intermediate output of their compiler (almost always guaranteed to get a good reception!) were dwindling, because compilers kept getting better. Interesting problems also sort of need to be *still relevant* in some way in order for folks to accept them as useful.

Initially, *anything* related to mobile development was more or less a wasteland on the site *because even the vendors didn't know what they were talking about*. That led some to make some pretty dire predictions about how we'd do in the future, but .. it mostly leveled out. Most new questions about a mobile app *still* revolve around someone not being able to make UX/Navigation work as expected, but, *that's a big part of what those programmers do every day*.

Therein lies the pattern, really.

Are you more into Python? Do you like nostalgic trips into some of the older mainframe stuff? Are you one of the folks that sees the potential for elegance in the myriad of ways one can implement inversion of control using PHP? You'll probably have a different outlook than I did, when I explained what undefined behavior meant for the hundredth time.

It's honestly way too big these days to measure without saying *who's asking?* Users find value in *most* posts written on any given day:

[image: vote graph]

And more than a tiny bit of those upvotes go to *great* answers on not-so-great questions. I won't pretend that uninteresting, repetitive questions *aren't* a problem, and I won't pretend that the scale that they come in these days doesn't put new urgency into the need to innovate and give users better tools to find duplicates, but *those are good problems to have, and we're working on them.*

Mostly, if you come to the site and show that you care about getting an answer as much as you'd hope we care about writing one, you'll get what you need. Our scale makes that not as simple as it used to be, and frustration tends to be commensurate with that, but we deal with problems as they come up. Some are just *much* harder and take a lot longer.

I don't think we have anything to worry about as long as we stay honest about what we see, and listen to what people tell us.

But the tl;dr - yeah, it has always been that way *from my perspective*, someone else might disagree :)

Answer (score 11):

#### Before:

Stack Overflow started with a very noble goal that was based around **Quality**.

Rep used to mean something, an objective measure of ones general knowledge of a [tag](/questions/tagged/tag), now it means less than nothing because there are so many gold badge holders in tags that are completely clueless about anything other than the most basic things, and then they are not completely competent in the basics most of the time.

#### Now:

When they took *Quality* out of the charter statement, that was when everything went down hill.

I believe they could lock down the site for 6 to 12 months, not allow any new questions or answers and the traffic would not dip more than single digit percentage points.

Because, **all the general knowledge, useful to the majority questions have been asked and answered over and over for at least 5 or 6 years now**.

> At this point, I think they should require at least a bronze badge in
> a tag before you can ask questions about it. That way, the only
> questions that get asked are the **hard** questions that are not
> trivial to debug with a step-debugger and solve in a few mins
> if the person was not a lazy incompetent mooch.

After 36 years, I am near the end of my career, I have probably 10 - 15 more years in software development, if my hands hold out that long. I think the current generation of developers entering the workplace in general are **terrible peers** and Stack Overflow is one of the main reasons why.

I have to train new college hires and mentor them and they supposedly have a degree in computer science and can not logically write out *fizz/buzz* level problems in pseudo-code on a whiteboard, much less give you any meaningful discussion about OOA/OOD vs Functional vs Imperative/Procedural paradigms.

Why should they, when they can just get on Stack Overflow and get someone that is bored to do their work for them. This is why I rarely answer questions anymore, they have to be something that is really a real problem that someone has demonstrated that they have tried everything and coming here is their **last resort**.

Most of the answers I have written in the recent years are to my own [*DenverCoder9*](https://xkcd.com/979/) questions that had to figure out myself in the end. *Wisdom of the Ancients* is a very fitting title.

Think about the peers you are creating when you answer questions that you know they have done no effort other than scribbling some vague requirement or paraphrased error message with *Someone please help me!* and do not respond to comments or worse argue that their question is fine when it is crap in the comments.

Think about the generation before you that is going to have to deal with this fallout.
It is real and it has been happening for a few years now. The quality of the peers in the industry is falling faster than every. Entropy is not to blame, **you** and **your peers** that spoon feed answers to unqualified muppets behind keyboards is what is to blame. These same people will be your manager eventually instead of being fired, they will just be promoted for taking credit for others work and float to the top on others efforts or a lazy manager unwilling to fire anyone will decide they can do less *harm* as a manager and make them your boss. *(Happens every day)*.

I tell anyone that asks be about entering the field to seriously consider what they will actually be doing and explain just how much of a bottom feeder *career* low barrier to entry field it has become.

Comment: The second paragraph resonates with me, seeing many examples of such users who don't seem to know what they're talking about, moderate questions like they know more than they do, or just flat out don't moderate.

Comment: The problem is most tag badge holders who spend time answering would rather *not* ask useful questions. Occasionally they post what's effectively a bug report, or a canonical in the hope of removing duplicates before they are posted. I can only presume they see asking a question as weakness, or go overboard with "self-answered Q&A is held to a higher standard", or think experts willing and able to help them don't exist, or they just "know it all" and *never* have questions.

Comment: The first sentence is okay, but below that... well... I see a lot of wild claims without anything backing them up aside from **bold** letters and hand waving.

Answer (score -1):

> However when we look at more modern ones, a majority if not all questions are to the tune of, "What's wrong with MY program?". Questions like these have little to no insight for users other than the OP.

No, because there is no such thing.

StackOverflow used to have a "Too Narrow" close reason, that essentially said exactly what you're saying here: that this question should be closed because it doesn't apply to anything except the specific circumstances of this one user.  We ended up getting rid of it years ago for various reasons, but the big one was because a lot of users--myself included--were sick of Googling some problem they'd run into and getting a SO link to a question that perfectly described their problem, but never got answered because it was closed as Too Narrow.  (Which is exactly what you'd expect, given how 1) widespread and 2) deterministic programming is!)

To be honest, proclaiming a question Too Narrow smacks of *extreme* arrogance.  It's essentially claiming that "I can't imagine how anyone else could benefit from this question, therefore nobody else could benefit from this question."  If you think about it, this is logically equivalent to the statement "anything I can't imagine does not exist."  Do you *really* want to proclaim yourself to be omniscient?

SO has been a better place since we got rid of Too Narrow, and recent reforms on fostering a more friendly and welcoming attitude are a major step in the right direction.   Let's please not screw it up!

Comment: Just because you can't imagine a way in which a human could correctly evaluate a question to be too narrow, does not mean it can't be. How about you abide by your own words?

Answer (score -33):

I'm a new user so I don't know how Stack Overflow was some years ago. However I think that programming is one of those disciplines where fixing a single programmer problem/error could potentially be useful for the entire user base.

Comment: your answer is so broad that it is right and wrong at the same time

Comment: Broad? Why? I exposed what I wanted to say clearly. People from all around the world could experience the same issues. The fact that one programmer asks help for his own error doesn't mean that fixing it won't benefit nobody else somewhere. 
Surely, each one should do it's own reasearch before asking for help. But sometimes the answer doesn't exist already.

Comment: "fixing a single programmer problem/error could potentially be useful for the entire user base" - sure, if the problem lends itself to that, and it's asked and answered well, but fixing a single problem can also be useful to only the asker. This question appears to be talking mostly about those that aren't useful to anyone else.

Comment: _"doesn't mean that fixing it won't benefit nobody else somewhere"_ you've got a triple negative there.

Comment: @TinyGiant I can't let you not be unsilent about this.

Comment: @TinyGiant we are not talking about grammar. There are people around the world that don't speak perfectly each language possible. I'm sure you can't write correctly in Indian.

Comment: @Dukeling. Even what you said is right. But let's analyze the question seriously. There are 2 scenarios: 1) The question is useless for everybody. Little or no users would answer or read, the question would be downvoted and relegated in SO meanderings and then deleted, and no one is harmed by a simple list of digits. 2) The question is useful for someone that will be happy to find the answer on SO. So because you, single user (or group of users), arbitrarily decide that a question is useless, someone around the world won't find the answer to his issue. Is this spirit of sharing ideas?

Comment: @GianlucaBezziccheri If you want to have a discussion about what questions we should and shouldn't close, you're probably better off posting that as a separate discussion, with plenty of examples of what you think we're currently wrongly closing. I, for one, am fairly confident about my judgement regarding how useful a question might be to others and thus also the validity of my close vote as a result of that.

Comment: @TinyGiant's comment is a fair example of something you could choose to take as either personal criticism or a request for improvement (the implication is that some people might have a hard time understanding that sentence, especially ones who don't understand English particularly well). Now of course it could've been an edit instead, or stated more politely, but that doesn't or can't always happen, and also this is Meta. Now a mod would almost certainly delete such arguably-useful comments on the main site, which links back to what's being discussed in the comments on the question.

Comment: @Dukeling Almost everyone is often fairly confident about his own judgement. That's why people often discuss and disagree. So that's not a surprise for me that you trust yourself. Anyway I imagine you're an experienced programmer, so that's legit and I won't discuss this point.

However did you take mine? I think that this mentality of considering personal requests useless damages some people in order to avoid nothing. Pointless.

Comment: @GianlucaBezziccheri It's hard to discuss this without any concrete examples (unless you want to discuss the merits of closing questions in general, which seems possible, since you seem to say closing "avoid[s] nothing" - if this is the case refer to my second-to-last comment). If a question is useless, it's useless, if it's not, it's not. In my very first comment, I agreed that such questions *can* be useful, but they need to be asked and answered correctly.

Comment: @Dukeling. That's exactly what I tried to say. A general statement. 
The fact that questions should be well asked is out of this discussion. It's obvious and I agree with you.
But the principal post written by teclnol states another thing: that personal request are "bad", in general. So I responded to that, not to other hypotethical arguments. In fact I'm quite surpised I obtained all of these "dislikes". I thought I said something obvious.

Comment: The problem with this answer is that it doesn't answer the question. It should be a comment on the question. "Is Stack Overflow becoming an error detection site?" "Well I think error detection can be good." See? It's not an answer to the question.

Comment: @Clonkex. Okk, that's legit. My fault. Next time I'll comment rather than answer.

Comment: @Clonkex Don't think they can comment with that amount of rep though. I would say they better of improving their answer instead.