# What is the Code of Conduct scandal about?

Tags: discussion

I've seen that a lot of people have been fired, then apologies from Stack Overflow staff, then un-firings, legal-sounding agreements, and then lots of moderators resigning in disgust etc, but the one thing that has been completely shrouded in mystery (or at least I have so far seen no explanation of) is "why?"

• What is it about the Code of Conduct (or whatever else the cause is) that has led to such anger and resentment? I am extremely opposed to the ideology of Social Justice, and I see that infecting lots of companies - is it something to do with Progressivism and Social Justice and the authoritarian way that these ideologies always try to dominate, control and thought police people into submissive "right-think" (i.e. have things in the Code of Conduct tried to enforce these authoritarian/religious dogmas)?

• I'm sure that many people have reasons for leaving that are private and personal so I would not want to pry into those people's reasons but have some people openly explained why they have left and what has led to them making that decision?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/393552/an-account-of-my-meeting-with-the-stack-overflow-management-team attempts to give an unbiased view of the status, as of Feb 4th.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333965/firing-mods-and-forced-relicensing-is-stack-exchange-still-interested-in-cooper and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/342039/firing-community-managers-stack-exchange-is-not-interested-in-cooperating-with have links to most of the history below the long lists of people who resigned as moderators in protest.

Comment: Nobody has been fired and subsequently unfired.

Comment: Scandal wasn't related as much to the Code of Conduct so much as the corporate response of stomping out any criticism of it both internally and externally. Also, no one was rehired. It was just a mass exodus of talent that has left us with a group that I cannot even criticize or my comment will be removed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The changes to the Code of Conduct were only the catalyst.  In fact, on their face alone, the CoC changes aren't all *that* problematic - sure, there <s>were</s> are plenty of warts with the original readings and original policy, but there was a revision to those and by and large, I don't think anyone here disagrees that people should be called what they want to be called.

What you're alluding to is kind of what led up to the whole thing.  [You can find more context in this Meta Stack Exchange post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333965/175248).  I won't rehash anything there - there's way too much and you can spare an afternoon if you're so inclined - but, at a high level:

- A highly respected **community** moderator was removed from their post due to [previously reported *existing* disagreement](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2019/10/01/stack_exchange_controversy/) with the existing CoC.  The issue was more about an *upcoming* change to the CoC.
- Moderators across the network were outraged at the situation and chose to resign in protest.
- Users who have been long contributors or janitors of the sites chose to resign in protest as well, contribute to various crowdfunding sites, or both - they're not mutually exclusive.
- More recently, that whole matter [has been settled in arbitration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340906/175248), and sure, a few people are unhappy with the way the whole arbitration deal went.
- Even *more* recently, some long-time CMs [were unceremoniously let go](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342039/175248).  Cue another round of outrage and resignations.

I should stress:  **we are all bound to the CoC through our continued use of the network.**  To disagree with that in any noticeable capacity is to not participate on the network.

Comment: Disagreement and non participation seem synonymous here. Surely you aren't suggesting some sort of organized walkout period similar to how tech generally combats being strong armed.

Comment: @TravisJ:  I'm suggesting **nothing**.  I'm reporting only the information in as neutral a manner as I can.

Comment: " I don't think anyone here disagrees that people should be called what they want to be called." I think most of people **do** disagree with this. There is an agreement (I hope) for the negative variant - people should not be called the way they don't want to be called. And there is an agreement that if someone demands to be called the infamous attack helicopter, nobody is expected to satisfy their wish, which falsifies your claim.

Comment: @TadeuszKopec: I think Makoto's point in regards to what people want to be called assumes that they are asking in good faith. I think that can be taken as read here, rather needing to be added to the answer explicitly.

Comment: @halfer Need for such clarifications (and should now moderators be other's faith guards to determine this?) proves to me that such requirements do not fit to CoC. It's like " Thou shalt love thy neighbour as thyself." The world would be a much netter place if everybody obeyed this, but trying to enforce this by law leads to disaster.

Comment: @Tadeusz: If a Codes of Conduct needs to be worded to handle edge-cases, then that is fine - it is not an argument against having a CoC. However, perhaps we disagree fundamentally on whether CoCs can be good or useful, and if so, that is OK.