# Cross your fingers and VoteToClose, or let loose the Roomba?

Tags: discussion, answers, vote-to-close

In the past I've answered questions that should have been (or were later) closed as "Too Broad", "Opinion-based", "Unclear", 0-Effort, or "Off-Topic for Debugging"<sup>(</sup>*<sup>)</sup>. To compensate, I feel like I should VTC those questions that are still open, even if my answer was accepted.

That said, I frequent low-traffic tags. Questions that I've VTC usually fail to meet the required 5 votes before accumulated votes expire. But I've also noted that in many of these cases, my answer (and perhaps pending a downvote) is the [only factor repressing the Roomba](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297072/3773066). The questions I then asked myself concerning these:

**Past**:

- [Can a question with an accepted answer be closed as unanswerable?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258432/3773066)

  The affirmative answer by Shog9, as I understand it, boils down to:

  ```
  if (!question.IsUseful)
  {
      if (answerer.IsAble)
      {
          question.Edit();
      }
      else
      {
          asker.IsHelped = true;
          question.Delete();
      }
  }
  ```
- [Should users be permitted to both answer and close a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/286283/3773066)

  Answers here vary from "*Yes*" to "*No*" and everything in-between. But most highly voted:

  > Yes, absolutely these users should be allowed to both answer and vote to close.

**Future**:

- [Should one advise on off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276637/3773066)

  > Don't ever answer an off-topic question, not via chat, comments, or any other way.

**Present**:

It seems clear that the correct course of action is to VTC and not make this mistake going forward. But given a low-traffic tag, stepping aside and unleashing the <strike>hound</strike> Roomba on a Question (formerly answered but only benefiting the author - who is since inactive) seems reasonable as well. **To VTC or Roomba?** That is the question.

---

<sup>(</sup>*<sup>)</sup> No examples provided to avoid [the Meta Effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251488/3773066).

Comment: So if an answerer doesn't think they can answer it - they should consider it answered and vote to delete the question? Huh?

Comment: @JonClements Funny when put that way! I meant "*shouldn't have answered*" more than "*doesn't think they can answer*" in this case. Some being years old - the question is whether to delete an answer to let the Roomba through, or just VTC.

Comment: Please DNI more TLAs.

Comment: Just have a look-see at how you are doing.  Navigate to your profile > Activity tab > votes > closure.  Go back at least a month.  You can easily see from the [square brackets] how many posts actually got closed.  Sadly it takes 10K rep to easily see deleted posts (purple background).  For me personally, VTC is only effective ~15% of the time, a DV invokes the Roomba ~50% of the time.  Often with my vote being the only one.  YMMV.

Comment: Wow, @Hans, 50% of the questions that you've downvoted have been Roomba'd? That's pretty incredible. The number is under 5% for me. There are too many people posting *answers* to low-quality questions. Either we have very different thresholds for a downvote, or you've been a lot luckier than I have.

Comment: @Cody - ouch, sorry about that.  If it makes you feel any better, I'm equally depressed about my VTC effectiveness.  Make sure to navigate back far enough, Roomba needs 30 days to really do its job.  For me personally, it is exceedingly rare to see a Roomba'd question with an answer.

Comment: My reading of Shog9's answer is `answer.Delete()` where you wrote `question.Delete()` - i.e. by deleting your answer, you enable the question to be garbage-collected.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

*If* you can edit the question, that's always preferable - it's a bit more work for you, but if you've already answered then you've already invested some amount of work; might as well put a bit more effort in to ensure that others can benefit from it. The primary value of Stack Overflow is the "long tail" of answers that'll only benefit a couple of people *ever* - that's the stuff you can't readily pull out of a textbook when you need it, so cleaning up a question to make it specific and clear preserves this utility.

If there's just no way to fix the question (hopelessly unclear, the author never came back to confirm your answer addressed the right problem, problem wasn't in the question to begin with...), then it's probably expedient to just remove your answer: it takes about the same effort as voting to close and requires no one else's participation.

I'd recommend reserving vote-to-close on older / more obscure questions for cases where the question might represent a serious stumbling-block for future readers: confusing, misleading, or a duplicate.

Comment: Err... aren't "removing own answers" considered not good? And "author never came back" is not good excuse for that? I'm pretty sure I've seen this several times on global meta - because I personally had to call for one of such remove answers to be restored.

Answer (score 17):

If a question cannot be answered, it should be closed. This includes cases where the question can only get salvaged by the OP.

You should not answer questions that should get closed, because it is most likely not possible to answer them in a meaningful way. This includes "gimme the codez" and "I get error please debug this for me" questions, which should not be answered as we don't want to encourage more of such crap on the site.

Since the very reason for closing a question is because it cannot be answered in its current form, it means that if you find yourself answering questions that should be closed, you are doing something wrong.

Comment: This doesn't really the question, which is about already existing answers on such old questions.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann How does it not? Either the question should be closed and then the answers will go with it, or it should not be closed. There is no need to touch the answers at all.

Comment: It is already a given that the question should be closed. The problem is that it is in a low-view tag, and thus will never accumulate enough close votes. Deleting the answer would possibly allow the Roomba to clean it up – should the OP delete his own answer to have this done?

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann The solution then is the [SO close vote review chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers). Cast your close vote on the question to be closed (if you have the privilege), leave a comment if needed, then go to the chat room and ask other user moderators to help you close it. They can also help deleting it, if that's necessary. Make sure to read the chat FAQ and such, but they are mostly a friendly bunch and will help you out.